# How to fix Lion Mail.app that keeps asking for keychain password?

Tags: macos, mail.app, keychain

I am getting this message every time I start mail.app.

I've read this [tech note](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4915?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), but neither checkbox is selected.

I've run Keychain First Aid, and no problems were found.

How do I fix Mail.app in Lion that keeps asking for keychain password?

UPDATE: Thanks everyone for the help.. I finally deleted the Keychain prefs. Re-entered passwords as required, and that worked.

Comment: I've experienced the same with Teamviewer. No solution still.

Comment: What does `codesign -vv /Applications/Mail.app/` return?

Comment: Thanks Lri, I will try this on Sunday, when I visit this client again.

Comment: responds: valid on disk, satisfies its Designated Requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me was deleting the Keychain prefs. Re-entered passwords as required, and that worked. phew!

Answer (score 2):

Quit Mail.  Open Keychain Access (Applications > Utilities).
Select your Login keychain.  Run Keychain First Aid (Keychain Access menu > Keychain First Aid).

Put in your password and run a verify.  If there's any red, select repair and run it.  Run another verify to make sure the errors are fixed.

Delete all of your mail entries.  In the search bar, try putting in things like "pop," "imap", "gmail", even your email address.  Quit Keychain Access.

Launch Mail.  Get into the preferences (Mail menu > Preferences > Accounts).  Fill in the passwords for each of your accounts.  Also, go to the SMTP/Outgoing server menu, and edit.  Fill in the passwords there as well.  Close and save.  Exit mail.

Launch mail.  Make sure it retrieves mail properly.  Send test emails to make sure it sends properly.

Done!

Comment: in the question, I wrote that I have tested Keychain. No issues. The computer uses iCloud so no POP/IMAP. It does receive mail ok. Other ideas are welcome. I'm not sure why you got upvoted though..

Comment: Why the hostility?  I may have been upvoted because this is a good start to repairing password remembering problems.  That aside: OK, instead of searching for those strings, search for iCloud, or "@me", or "@mac".  Am I dumbing this down too much for you?  Basically, get rid of any keychain entries that are related to the email address you're having problems with.  Does any other application have password issues?  If not, the next logical step would be to blow away mail prefs.

Comment: Apologies Harv. Long Day. Thanks for the follow up. I'll look at it on Sunday.

Comment: We've all had that, it's not a problem.  Let's get your issue dealt with!

Comment: Thanks Harv. Yes, having the same issue with FaceTime, iPhoto, a number of others.

Comment: Are they all trying to connect using the same account?  Run Disk Utility, and do a verify/repair if anything shows up.  Sounds odd and disconnected from the problem, I know: please do it anyway.  If they're all using the same account, try creating a new login keychain, signing in to al those services, and restarting.  Is the problem still present?

Comment: I've tried it all, and I'm still routinely being asked for my passwords by MS Outlook 2011. Each time, I enter the password and again click the box to store it in the keychain. In my case, methinks this is Apple and Microsoft just not playing nice together.

Comment: @GeneJ I wouldn't write it off so easily.  You're right: in my experience the Office suite tends to act a bit funny in general, but I have seen Outlook remember passwords properly.  Keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

@Hoshts I have just experienced the same problem with TeamViewer.
In my case, it was a problem with the proxy.
In the Preferences, I had to manually set the proxy settings (instead of Use webbrowser proxy) and it worked fine.