# How can I get Outlook to stop asking for a Keychain login if I don't want to use keychain?

Tags: macos, password

I don't want to use keychain for my passwords so I have not added any passwords to keychain.  This means that every time Outlook checks for mail it creates a popup window asking for my keychain password.  I have seen [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61038/how-to-fix-lion-mail-app-that-keeps-asking-for-keychain-password) but this seems to require that I use keychain for password management.

Is there a way to get Outlook (actually everything) to stop looking for my keychain password?

I am using OS X 10.5.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keychain as you may be aware by now is the main system OSX uses to store your passwords. Anything you ask to be stored is sent to the keychain. Therefore if you choose not to save any passwords you will be asked to enter the password in every time it is required, which is what the keychain is designed to do.

If you do not want to save passwords to the keychain, then no you cannot get around the keychain pop up question.

Comment: So it's "my way or the highway" huh?  bummer.

Comment: Yup unfortunately - any reason you do not want to use the keychain? It makes life a whole lot easier.

Comment: I just don't like to store my passwords on the system.  I change passwords a lot for a bunch of reasons and I just wind up having a lot of issues with out of date stored passwords.  It is just extra complications that I don't need.  I don't mind entering my password when it is needed (like when I open my inbox) but Keychain is literally interrupting my work like every 10 minutes to ask again if I want to enter my keychain password - it isn't asking for my email password that I only have to enter once.